# understanding "mount" as a concept in the OS

Tags: filesystems, mount, terminology

I want to understand what *mounting* is. It is used in different contexts and situations (directories, flash drives, network cards, etc) and I can't find resources which:

1. Describe the mount concept;
2. Explain the actions taken by the computer/OS/utility when a mount is performed;
3. How and in which situations is mount used;
4. Which features in the Linux `mount` command are of frequent use and some examples.

Comment: This is not a real question. I mean, it is so broad, to answer it one had to write an essay spanning several letter pages. Please try to state it in a way that a clear answer becomes possible.

Comment: Well, you don't need to give a complete answer, maybe some pointers, insight, the common sense understanding etc, anything will do, for the clueless:)

Comment: This is very similar to [What is meant by mounting a device in Linux?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3192/what-is-meant-by-mounting-a-device-in-linux), but I suppose it asks a bit more

Comment: If we were to answer this question, would we be doing your homework for you?

Comment: no, its not for homework, I graduated a long time ago, look at my profile page and my webpage link to check that out.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As [fschnitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1941/fschmitt)
points out, a comprehensive answer to this would likely be a chapter
in a systems administration manual, so I'll try just to sketch the
basic concepts.  Ask new questions if you need more detail on specific
points.

In UNIX, all files in the system are organized into a *single*
directory tree structure (as opposed to Windows, where you have a
separate directory tree for each drive).

There is a "root" directory, which is denoted by `/`, which
corresponds to the top directory on the main drive/partition (in the
Windows world, this would be `C:`).  Any other directory and file in
the system can be reached from the root, by walking down
sub-directories.

How can you make other drives/partitions visible to the system in such
a unique tree structure?  You *mount* them: mounting a drive/partition
on a directory (e.g., `/media/usb`) means that the top directory on
that drive/partition becomes visible as the directory being mounted.
Example: if I insert a USB stick in Windows I get a new drive, e.g.,
`F:`; if in Linux I mount it on directory `/media/usb`, then the
top directory on the USB stick (what I would see by opening the `F:`
drive in Windows) will be visible in Linux as directory `/media/usb`.
In this case, the `/media/usb` directory is called a "mount point".

Now, drives/partitions/etc. are traditionally called "(block) devices"
in the UNIX world, so you always speak of mounting a device on a
directory.  By abuse of language, you can just say "mount this device"
or "unmount that directory".

I think I've only covered your point 1., but this could get you
started for more specific questions.

Check [this](http://ultra.pr.erau.edu/%7Ejaffem/tutorial/file_system_basics.htm) for further reading.

Comment: so, when a flash drive is mounted into /media/usb, the OS maps commands like 'ls' from this directory to the flash drive to get the output?

Comment: @Vass yes, that is precisely what happens.

Comment: @RiccardoMurri, So basically, mount is a redundant word and concept. Just use the word "**link**". Link the drive, Unlink the drive, The linkpoint is x.

Comment: @Pacerier Well, no: the term used everywhere in the Linux/UNIX world is "mount".  The word "link" is used to refer to a different concept: see e.g. https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-unixlinux-symbolic-soft-and-hard-links.html

Comment: So, Can I mount a drive/device that is not already formatted as a particular file system? I thought mount could only attach files systems into the virtual file namespace?

Comment: @DonSlowik No, you can only mount devices that have been formatted with a filesystem: mounting means that the top directory on the device becomes visibile at the mount point.  (You can still operate on unformatted devices, e.g. to format them, but not mount them.)

Comment: Right, so we don’t “mount” a device or partition, we mount a file system that has been formatted onto a particular device or partition. From man mount(1): “mount attaches a file system to the file system hierarchy...”. So we first operated on device to partition, then on the partition with mkfs. So my question becomes: it seems those devices and partitions are already part of the fs under /, how did they get those names (e.g. /dev/hda1) without having been mounted? (They did need names to be operated on.) And what’s in /proc/ likewise wasn’t a fs that was mounted at /proc...

Comment: Well, that's a separate question and a valid one to ask on this site :-)

Answer (score 28):

**In Unix everything is a file.**

These files  are organized in a tree structure, beginning at the root `/`.

Your filesystem or filesystems will then be mounted at the appropriate places in your `/` according your `/etc/fstab` file. This file contains information about your filesystems, which device they belong to and to which point they will get mounted to - the **mountpoint**.

Thats the "mount concept".

It is not limited to disks and other blockdevices, here are some examples involving mount:

- Mount a representation of your running kernel under /proc
- Mount a special log partition (other device, "logfriendly" filesystem) under /var/log
- Install different systems and mount just one home directory
- Mount remote directories for example via NFS to your system
- Mount a image of a cd to a specific directory

Comment: then in the directory you mounted something too, you can 'cd' into there and see all the files?

Comment: Yes. You can "cd into" your mountpoint and see the files :-)

Comment: can you 'mount' a directory to another directory? can you mount an input stream into a directory? what are some things other than devices you can mount?

Comment: you can't mount a directory into another, but there are hardlinks and symlinks for that. you can't mount an input stream directly, because theres no filesystem behind an input stream. you can mount it indirectly with an appropriate kernelmodule, see the last point I mentioned (cdimage). For the last point, see my examples and FuseFS.

Comment: Kernel ----> Filesystem Module ----> Device / Application / Whatever

Comment: @echox, So where's fstab in mac?

Comment: "In Unix everything is a file" sounds very profound and everyone nods when it is spoken, but what are the specific implications of this? Are there some philosophical ramifications?

Answer (score 7):

I found [this resource](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount) to be helpful:

> Data on a computer, as you may know, is stored in binary as a series
> of 1s and 0s. The way these are stored on a device and their structure
> is called the "filesystem". In Linux devices are referenced in /dev.
> Data is not actually stored on a device so you cannot access this data
> by going into /dev, this is because it is stored inside the filesystem
> on the device so you need to access these filesystems somehow.
> Accessing such filesystems is called "mounting" them, and in Linux
> (like any UNIX system) you can mount filesystems into any directory,
> that is, make the files stored in that filesystem accessible when you
> go into a certain directory. These directories are called the "mount
> points" of a filesystem.