# Youtube on Linux

Tags: linux, youtube-dl

I downloaded youtube_dl and found it where it is on my C drive - being a New User for Linux Mint Cinnamon I do not know how to Run the youtube_dl to DOWNLOAD Songs etc. like I did on Realplayer in the past!

Can some one advise how to RUN it ----I tried SUDO -youtube_dl etc. NO LUCK!!!

Regards,

Comment: "C drive?"  On Linux?  I'm guessing this is a newbie mix of terms--suggested reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3253/74085

Comment: what was the result of running `SUDO -youtube_dl etc`?

Answer (score 2):

The standard to download using this tool is simply

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?<videoid>
```

in your terminal application.

This will download the video file.  If you just want the audio (as you mention getting songs), add the `-x` parameter:

```
youtube-dl -x https://www.youtube.com/watch?<videoid>
```

That's about it.  For more information, have a look at the [tutorial for beginners](https://ostechnix.com/youtube-dl-tutorial-with-examples-for-beginners/).

Answer (score 2):

## Use the package manager to install software

You can try this.

**First:** Sync the package database.

```bsh
sudo apt update
```

**Then:** Install youtube-dl.

```bsh
sudo apt install youtube-dl
```

**After installing it this way you just run the command**

```bsh
youtube-dl "https://......"
```