# Can anyone explain the output of mount?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, linux-kernel

I'm getting the following output when the `mount` command is executed.

```
[root@]# mount
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sda3 on /home type ext4 (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /root/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

I'm not able to understand the output of this command.
Can anyone give the explanation for this output?

Comment: It tells you what devices are mounted in what locations, and what type of filesystem it has.  What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: what are the different filesystems in Linux ?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3192/what-is-meant-by-mounting-a-device-in-linux

Answer (score 18):

Running [`mount`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) without arguments will output a list of filesystems mounted  according to the table of mounted filesystems in `/etc/mtab`. The `/etc/mtab` file is typically maintained by `mount` and `umount`, although in some environments (such as live CDs) `/etc/mtab` may be a symlink to `/proc/self/mounts`.

The kernel maintains the information of mounted filesystems in the current mount namespace in [`/proc/[pid]/mounts`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc). Traditionally, the Linux kernel exposed all mounts via `/proc/mounts`, but since the introduction of per-process mount namespaces in kernel version 2.4.19, `/proc/mounts` is a symlink to `/proc/self/mounts`. The format of these files is documented in the [manual page for `fstab`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab).

Note that as `/etc/mtab` is maintained by user space programs, it is entirely possible for the contents of `/etc/mtab` and `/proc/self/mounts` to differ. This can occur if filesystems are mounted or unmounted directly via the `mount()` and `umount()` system calls, without going through the `mount` and `umount` programs. Differences between separate mount namespaces can also cause discrepancies between `/etc/mtab` and `/proc/self/mounts`.

Each line in the `mount` output is of the form:

```
fs_spec on fs_file type fs_vfstype (fs_mntopts)
```

where

- `fs_spec` describes the block device or remote filesystem to be mounted.
- `fs_file` describes the mount point for the filesystem.
- `fs_vfstype` describes the type of the filesystem.

  A list of filesystems the current kernel supports is exposed via [`/proc/filesystems`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/filesystems). Detailed documentation for each filesystem can be found in the [Linux kernel tree](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/).
- `fs_mntopts` describes the mount options associated with the filesystem.

  Filesystem independent options are listed in the [`mount` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount). For filesystem specific options consult the [kernel tree documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/) for that filesystem.

Comment: Traditionally, and still the case on most systems, the information comes from `/etc/mtab` which `mount`/`umount` maintain. Some Linux distributions replace `/etc/mtab` with a symlink to `/proc/self/mount` but not all do.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks for your comment. I edited the answer accordingly and added a note on the implications.

Answer (score 5):

At first you need to know differences between *Virtual Filesystems* and *Physical Filesystems* (check google).

`proc`, `sysfs`, `tmpfs,devpts`, `sun_rpc` and `gvfs-fuse-daemon` are Virtual filesystems.

/dev/sda1  and /dev/sda3 are media devices: physical filesystems.

`proc`: `proc` is a Virtual filesystems for managing processes, you can see every PID and another resources.

`sysfs`: is another Virtual filesystem managed by the kernel; it assists `proc`, though not in `PIDs` but in hardware and another resources.

`/dev/pts` : on GNU/Linux, you have virtual terminals and real terminals, for real terminals you can access via: `/dev/tty1`, `/dev/tty2`, `/dev/tty2` swtich via `CTRL+ALT+F1..8` But for virtual terminals, you have `/dev/pts/` directory, it contains `/dev/pts/0`, `1`, `2` and so on each digit for one virtual terminal.

`/dev/shm` : shm is abbreviation of SHared Memory, it's a place of sharing data.

`RPC` : Remote Procedure call.

`tmpfs` : When the kernel needs space for each task, mount it type. Such as `/tmp`

**NOTE:** At first, read about Virtual filesystems then read about mounting.

Comment: "logical" filesystems isn't the usual term. "Virtual" filesystems is more common.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh That's not the meaning of "vfs" (you've invented your own, this isn't the definition used in Linux kernel development), "virtual filesystem" is the standard name for this.

Comment: Ohi read wikipedia, sorry for wrong info, i updated my post.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh You should also use the term "namespace" carefully because in the context of the Linux kernel the term is heavily associated with [kernel namespaces](http://lwn.net/Articles/531114/). You also mention that `proc` shows every PID, but it this is not strictly true since PID namespaces were introduced in 2.6.24. When certain conditions are met, `proc` only shows resources associated with processes in the current PID namespace.

Comment: I updated......!

Comment: The terminals accessed by CTRL+ALT+F1..F8 are not real terminals but ["virtual consoles"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console).

Answer (score 4):

by default the `mount` command displays a list of media devices currently mounted on the system.There are four pieces of information the mount command provides:

- The device location of the media
- The mount point in the virtual directory where the media is mounted
- The file-system type
- The access status of the mounted media

as in your example output of mound command in the first row:

- `/dev/sda2` is the device location
- `/` is the mount point where your media is mounted
- `ext4` the file system type
- `(rw)` access status which is (read and write)

there may be many other `options` as in other rows of your example for the forth column which you can find in detail in this atricle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab

Comment: ok I edited the answer :)

Comment: That's much better.