# Why does Linux need to have both `/dev/cdrom` and `/media/cdrom`?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

Inspired by [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3192/what-is-meant-by-mounting-a-device-in-linux). Why does Linux need both `/dev/cdrom` and `/media/cdrom`?

Why not just access files on the cdrom through `/dev/cdrom`?

Comment: Why does it have both `/dev/sda1` and `/`?

Comment: @immibis Yes, there do exist some other ways to ask this question. Thanks for pointing it out.  I didn't realize it at first.  :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why do we have both `/dev/cdrom` and `/media/cdrom`?

Why do we have both `/dev/sda2` and `/home`?

Basically, `/dev/cdrom` is a *file*. When you access it, you are accessing the individual bits and bytes on the CD (if there is one). Whereas `/media/cdrom` is a *folder*. When you access it, you are accessing the *files* stored on the CD.

Similarly, `/dev/sda2` represents the raw contents of the second partition on the first harddrive. You would write to this directly, e.g., if you wanted to format the partition. (The `mkfs` program literally opens `/dev/sda2` or whatever, and writes particular bit patterns onto it.) You then *mount* `/dev/sda2` at, say, `/home`, and now you can access the actual *files*. As you access the files through the mount point, the filesystem driver is reading and writing the underlying device file.

This is just the way Unix does things.

Comment: So I guess `/media/cdrom` is implemented on top of `/dev/cdrom` from a software perspective. Right?

Comment: @smwikipedia Pretty much, yes.

Comment: "This is just the way Unix does things." No, in Unix, everything is a file *scnr*. On a more serious note though, in the Hurd, you do actually mount file systems by putting a translator on a device file that then presents itself as a folder with the content of the FS, even though it's just a process mediating the access to that single file (you still have the distinction between mount point and device file though). Hope that wasn't too confusing.

Answer (score 41):

`/media/cdrom` is a convention for the *mountpoint*, while `/dev/cdrom` is the special device that could be mounted on the former.

You need both, because they serve different purposes: most applications do not read directly from the special device, but can read from a filesystem (something that is mounted)

Comment: I think @smwikipedia ask about why `/dev/cdrom` is not used as mountpoint, needing to mount it in another place. I used to think about this also in the past since it's already possible to mount a filesystem on top of a file (descriptor), maybe it's common to do otherwise for legacy reasons...

Comment: @Piranna Yes, you are right. I do want to know why not just directly use `/dev/cdrom` to access CDROM files, be it called *mount point* or whatever.

Comment: @ThomasDickey You said `Most applications do not read directly from the special device`. I think that's because a file system is easier to interact with than a raw block device. If so, I think my own answer is similar to yours.

Comment: If you're dealing with files and directories, then you need a file system and hence the mount point. If you are dealing with the raw data - like when CD burning or copying by `dd` - there may not be even a valid filesystem, so you need the device file.

Comment: @smwikipedia for the same reason `/dev/sda1` may be mounted on `/`.

Comment: @rexkogitans That doesn't explain why you wouldn't use `/dev/cdrom` itself as the mounting point.

Comment: Using `/dev/cdrom` itself as the mountpoint would interfere with applications that use the device, e.g., for controlling it (since a mounted filesystem would present a different driver to applications than the device).   That's why devices are mounted in a different place (as a filesystem).

Answer (score 21):

(Thanks for so many answers to my question. After searching the web for a while, I want to share my own understanding.)

According to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file):

> In Unix-like operating systems, a device file or special file is **an
> interface for a device driver** that appears in a file system as if it
> were an ordinary file.

According to [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html):

> The mount command serves **to attach the filesystem** found on some device
> to the big file tree.

So, I think there are 2 different levels of software abstraction here:

- `/dev/cdrom` is a device special file. It abstract the CD-ROM hardware as a block IO device. This abstraction is provided by the **device driver**.
- `/media/cdrom` is a mount point for a filesystem. So it provides a higher level of abstraction of the CD-ROM hardware, i.e. as a file system. Such as [ISO-9660 file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660). And this abstraction is provided by the **file system driver**.

So basically, 2 different file locations for 2 different levels of abstraction. And in different scenarios, we may need different one. I think other OS such as Windows also provide such different options only that Linux unifies it into a single file hierarchy.

(I guess maybe I should do some experiment by writing some C code on Linux to interact with both `/dev/cdrom` and `/media/cdrom`. And see how everything goes on.)

(I will keep learning and refine my understanding as appropriate.)

Comment: One final bit of info: the /dev/cdrom special file (and actually everything in /dev) is actually just a way to give a name and permissions to a pair of numbers that reference something in the magic parts of the kernel. If you know the magic numbers, the /dev files can be recreated using them eveneif they were deleted; take a look at the docs for the "mknod" command for more esotrica.

Comment: "I think other OS such as Windows also provide such different options only that Linux unifies it into a single file hierarchy." – Windows is very similar, actually. In Unix, everything is a file, and other kinds of objects (devices, kernel objects, …) are represented as files (e.g. in `/dev`, `/proc`, or `/sys`). There is a single file hierarchy, and objects form subhierarchies. In Windows, everything is an object, files are just special kinds of objects. There is a single unified object hierarchy, and filesystems form subhierarchies. But there are two distinct entities, just like in Unix:

Comment: a device object for the CD-ROM drive, and a mount point for the filesystem on that CD-ROM. Not also that in modern Windows, the mount point no longer has to be a drive letter, it can be mounted anywhere inside another filesystem, just like in Unix.

Answer (score 5):

- You can see that `/dev/cdrom` is actually a **block special file** which is a [**device file**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Block_devices).

  ```
  $ ls -l /dev/cdrom
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Mar 18 17:00 /dev/cdrom -> sr0
  $ ls -l /dev/sr0
  brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 Mar 18 17:00 /dev/sr0
  ```
- Visit [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard):

  > `/media` Mount points for removable media such as CD-ROMs (appeared in FHS-2.3).

  ```
  $ ls -ld /media/cdrom/
  drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 15  2015 /media/cdrom/
  ```

  This directory contains subdirectories which are used as mount points for
  removeable media such as floppy disks, cdroms and zip disks.

So, `/dev/cdrom` and `/media/crdom` are totally different thing. one is a block/device ***file*** for CD-ROM whereas another is a ***directory*** for mounting it!

Answer (score 1):

A good source of information that covers this (and more) can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

- /media => Mount points for removable media such as CD-ROMs (appeared in FHS-2.3).
- /mnt => Temporarily mounted filesystems.

Comment: You don't answer the part about `/dev/cdrom` - while the question doesn't reference `/mnt`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why not just access files on the cdrom through /dev/cdrom

In addition to the answers already provided, you cannot use `/dev/cdrom` to access the cdrom content because mounting `/dev/cdrom` (the files present on the cdrom) on top of `/dev/cdrom` (the device) is a forbidden operation.

Under Linux, you can only mount a file system on top of an existing directory, not on top of an existing file or device.

Should the OS allow such an operation, a side effect would be accessing the original `/dev/cdrom` would no more be possible after the mount.

Should you really want to access your cdrom though `/dev/cdrom`, here is a hack that should work:

```
umount /media/cdrom
mv /dev/cdrom /dev/cdrom-org
mkdir /dev/cdrom
mount /dev/cdrom-org /dev/cdrom
```

Of course, there is no much point doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Linux device drivers are exposed as special files. Utilities/applications perform file operations on these files (ioctl calls) to control the devices.

One example of a utility that would make calls to a special file to control the device is "mount".

The mount utility is a program with the purpose to present the data on the cdrom device as a dir/file structure. This is a well understood and convenient way for users to use the data by simple reading it from the file structure that the mount utility created.

A cdrom device supports many other operations on the special file e.g. to open/close the tray etc.

Many special files used to control devices are stored in /dev to make it simple for developers/users of utilities to know where to look for it.

Furthermore, utilities that present data on devices (e.g. cdrom, sdcard, memory stick etc.) as a dir/file structure does so in /media to make it simple for developers/users to know where to look.

Both are therefore used for its own purpose.

Comment: It's helpful. I feel `/dev` is just like the `Windows Device Manager`. And thanks for pointing out `A cdrom device supports many other operations on the special file e.g. to open/close the tray etc.`