# How can I remove the eject icon without formatting?

Tags: mount, hard-disk, nautilus

I have problem with my Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus. The problem started after I changed operating systems from Windows to Ubuntu. I have one disk with my personal documents. After changing to Ubuntu, I always see an eject. So how can I remove the eject icon without formatting the disk?

[image: My Disk Named "J"]

I want to remove the eject icon named "J".
File System Type : NTFS

Comment: Why do you want to remove the icon? There's nothing wrong with it, that just lets you unmount the drive.

Comment: ejecting the disk will not format it. by the way what is "one disk with my personal document" ? an ISO file ? a partition ? an mounted USB ?

Comment: @james, I moved our discussion to [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62934/discussion-on-answer-by-terdon-how-can-i-remove-the-eject-icon-without-formattin) please ping me (`@terdon`) if you want to continue.

Comment: Thanks @terdon the problem is solved, i am just afraid for what i am doing for next time

Comment: @Archemar personal document is including your personal file i mean. Sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is supposed to be there. Disks on Linux (and Windows, but never mind) [are *mounted*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3194/22222) at a specific location. That button would let you unmount this disk.

There's nothing wrong with it, and it can be useful. If you don't want it, just ignore it, but there is no reason to remove it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62934/discussion-on-answer-by-terdon-how-can-i-remove-the-eject-icon-without-formattin).